# How to change value in XML file using sed in Linux?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, sed

I have a task and I am having some trouble understanding how to change the values of two different nodes in an XML-file in Linux, but with the same tags in it.

I have this XML-file:

```
<logger name="my.test.module">
  <level value="error"/>
  <appender-ref ref="file-module"/>
</logger>

<logger name="my.test.module2">
  <level value="error"/>
  <appender-ref ref="file-module2"/>
</logger>
```

And after using `sed`, is it possible to get a result some kind like this?

Hello Thor. Unfortunately I am using windows based xmlstarlet, because on the destination OS it is not possible to install it.

I am trying to do from your advise

```
xml edit -S -O \
  --update '/log4j:configuration/logger[@name="ru.crystals.transport"]/level/@value' \
  --value all log4j.xml
```

But nothing happens.

The part of file like this:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<logger name="my.test.module">
        <level value="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file-module"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="my.test.module2">
        <level value="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file-module2"/>
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: The best way to do this is not `sed` but rather `xsltproc`, a Linux XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing XML with sed is error-prone. Rather, make your input into valid XML, e.g. with GNU sed:

```bash
<infile.xml sed -e '1i\<xml>' -e '$a\</xml>'
```

Now edit the data with XPATHs in xmlstarlet, e.g.:

```bash
<infile.xml sed -e '1i\<xml>' -e '$a\</xml>'                |
xmlstarlet edit -S -O                                       \
  --update '//logger[@name="my.test.module"]/level/@value'  \
  --value  all                                              \
  --update '//logger[@name="my.test.module2"]/level/@value' \
  --value  trace
```

Output:

```xml
<xml>
<logger name="my.test.module">
  <level value="all"/>
  <appender-ref ref="file-module"/>
</logger>

<logger name="my.test.module2">
  <level value="trace"/>
  <appender-ref ref="file-module2"/>
</logger>
</xml>
```